# Display Open tickets excluding overdue tickets through Open tab in OsTicket

Tags: ticket-system, osticket

I want to display Open tickets only through Open tab ,currently Open tab includes overdue tickets as well.
Please guide.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Issue resolved.

I added the flag "&showoverdue=false" in the default case statement of switch in "tickets.inc.php" and its working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

I use this, in css file:

```
#subnav6.overdueTickets
{
   visibility:hidden !important;
   width: 0px !important;
   margin: 0px !important;
   padding: 0px !important;
}
```